# ng-if = 'false' is hiding the DIV

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, angular-ng-if

I have the `ng-click` and `ng-if` directives on the same div.

Since the `click` variable is initially set to `false` the **box** DIV does not appear. If I set `click` to `true` or use `!click` for `ng-if` directive, then the **box** DIV appears but still no animation occurse upon clicking.

If I remove the `ng-click` from **box** DIV and add it to another DIV or button to do the toggle, animation works. However, the **box** DIV is still hidden initially and also disappears after the animation run.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="animationApp" ng-controller="c1">

  <div ng-click="click=!click" ng-if="click" class="box"></div>

</div>
```

JS

```
angular.module('animationApp', ['ngAnimate'])

    .controller('c1', function ($scope, $animate, $timeout) {

        $scope.click = false;

})

;
```

CSS

```
.box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: indianred;
}

.box.ng-enter {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}

.box.ng-enter-active {
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}

.box.ng-leave {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
}

.box.ng-leave-active {
  transform: rotateZ(0deg);
}
```

Demo
https://jsfiddle.net/ae8kwzxg/93/

Comment: How about just change to ng-if="!click"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is do nothing: `"ng-click="click=!click"`.

The reason why is not work is because your `$scope.click` variable is primitive type (bool). It means in this line: `ng-click="click=!click"` click variable is a copy of your `$scope.click` variable and you just change the copy but not the actual `$scope.click`. If you will change your `$scope.click` variable to object, for example `$scope.click = {active:true}`
and change your HTML to:   `<div ng-click="click.active=!click.active" ng-if="click.active" class="box"></div>`
It will work.

But better way is always do assignments in function:

```
<div ng-app="animationApp" ng-controller="c1">

  <div ng-click="clicked()" ng-if="click" class="box"></div>

</div>
```

And your controller will be:

```
angular.module('animationApp', ['ngAnimate'])

    .controller('c1', function ($scope, $animate, $timeout) {

        $scope.click = true;

        $scope.clicked = function(){
            $scope.click = !$scope.click;
        }
})
```

This is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/ae8kwzxg/94/

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the correction. However, after the animation the DIV disappears. Why is this so? This behaviour is not in the ng-leave. What does make it disappear and how can I prevent this?

Comment: So use ng-class binding. Bind your class on action and change your css selector from angular class to your custom class name

Comment: See this demo of image rotation: https://codepen.io/runamuk0/pen/OPNXyV.

Comment: So, hiding the element is a characteristics of ng-enter and ng-leave, right? Thanks for your help again.